# Pagination in codeigniter for different functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

I am working on codeigniter and i want to include pagination in frontend.
I have been using normal pagination code in which the pagination links redirect to particular function in the controller file. But i am using the same view file i.e the same pagination for different url changes for example a product list in which there are latest products, filtered products etc. So i am using the same view file for different controller functions but the pagination redirects to only one function and i want to redirect it to different function. Can anyone help me out so that i can redirect to different functions according to url changes ?

Comment: What you need to do is abstract your code, that generates the pagination, and put this in it own method. You need to make the method so that the URL can be passed in (making it dynamic) then it can be used on wherever you need.

Comment: use a variable that holds your function name

Comment: i am using bootsrap pagination. Can we pass the current url in that ?

Comment: In view should only print the pagination, but generating the pagination should happen inside the controller function.